# Calculate tip on javascript. What wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html

It kept on showing "NaN" and I don't know why. The text field should show the 10% and 20% of what its inputted in the "How much for dinner waiter?"

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function tipp()
        {
        var tip = alert("You Calculated The tip " + document.form1.textfield.value + " in the Textfield.");
        tip = parseFloat(tip);
        var tf2 = tip * .10;
        var tf3 = tip * .20;
        document.form1.textfield2.value = tf2;
        document.form1.textfield3.value = tf3;
        }
</script>
    <form name="form1">
        How much was dinner,waiter?<input type="text" name="textfield" id="tip"><br><br>
        <input type="button" onClick = "tipp()" value="Calculate Tip"><br><br>
        10% <input type="text" id="textfield2"><br><br>
        20%<input type="text3" id="textfield3"><br><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert` has no return value, so `tip` will be `undefined`. `parseFloat(undefined)` is `NaN`. All math calculations with `NaN` yield `NaN`.

Instead of using the `alert`'s return value, get the value from your field:

```
var tip = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tip").value);
```

**Example** (I removed the alert, I have no idea what you were trying to show there; also, I used `getElementById` for all the fields):

```js
function tipp() {
  var tip = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tip").value);
  var tf2 = tip * .10;
  var tf3 = tip * .20;
  document.getElementById("textfield2").value = tf2;
  document.getElementById("textfield3").value = tf3;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  How much was dinner,waiter?
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="tip">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onClick="tipp()" value="Calculate Tip">
  <br>
  <br>10%
  <input type="text" id="textfield2">
  <br>
  <br>20%
  <input type="text3" id="textfield3">
  <br>
  <br>
</form>
```